# mongoengine map_reduce output into a new collection throws ns doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoengine

I'm a beginner with MongoDB and Mongoengine, and I'm trying to use the map_reduce functionality from Django.

I'm using using this code to do a map-reduce job over my collection, and save the results to a new collection:

```
from mongengine import Document

class MyClass(Document):
    meta = {"db_alias": "mydatabase"}

...

map_f = "function() { emit(this.foo, this.bar); }"
reduce_f = "function(key, values) { return values[0]; }"
output_collection_name = "mynewcollection"

result = MyClass.objects.map_reduce(map_f, reduce_f, output_collection_name)

first_mapreduce_doc = result.next()  # exception thrown
```

However, this throws an "ns doesn't exist" exception.

To my understanding, with this syntax, the database name should be the same as where "MyClass" documents are stored (which exists), and the collection "mycollection" should be created by this call. So what exactly "doesn't exist"?

Am I doing something wrong? Am I supposed to somehow create the empty collection manually before making this call?

When i use:

```
output_collection_name = "inline"
```

it works perfectly fine.

Thanks in advance!

- Python version: 2.7
- Django version: 1.7.1
- MongoDB version: 2.6.7
- MongoEngine version: 0.8.7

Comment: Does the output collection exist already? You can only output to a collection that already exists.

Comment: I thought it would create the empty collection, when needed. I went through the entire API reference for MongoEngine, and there is no command for creating an empty collection. How do I do this (without calling the MongoDB command line utility)?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not terribly familiar with mongoengine. I think that you are right that there's no `create_collection` function, and there's no function to run a command either. You'll have to access the PyMongo layer underneath mongoengine to be able to create the collection from Python.